# Prove that $0$ is a partial limit of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence, such that $-5$ and $5$ are two partial limits of the sequence.
> In addition, for all $n$, $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{n}$.
>
> Prove that $0$ is a partial limit of the sequence $a_n$.

The question is a bit unclear. The statement in the absolute value above suggests using Cauchy Sequences, but I don't know if and how to do it.
$a_n$ does not converge since it has more than one partial limit. How can use it?

Thanks!